# Is there a two keypress way to open new tab in Pentadactyl?

Tags: firefox, pentadactyl

Workflow before Pentadactyl was: Command-T, start typing URL. (2 keypresses)
Now, it's :tabopen URL (6-8 keypresses, or :)

Anyone know a better way to reduce the keypresses neeeded to open a new tab?

Comment: For anyone looking for a two keypress way to open your homepage in a new tab in Pentadactyl: ```gH```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pentdactyl keys are all case-sensitive, so you'll want to use `t` (lower-case letter "t"). This key is mapped to the command `:tabopen`. So, to visit Reddit, I just type `treddit.com<Enter>`, which looks like this in the command bar: `:tabopen reddit.com`.

As you saw, `T` (upper-case letter "t") does `:tabopen <current url>`, then waits for you to edit it.

Comment: that is the reason I was wondering why you were getting a different fucnctionality for the same key !.

Answer (score 0):

1.You just type out T to open new tab .
2.Type O to open in the same tab.

Both should be followed by the url. I hope this was your doubt.

PS: please use :help it has mentioned your question .

Comment: No, sorry that doesn't answer my question. T opens the current URL. I'm looking for a quick way to open a new URL in a new tab.

Comment: i dont quite get you !. if you want to open suppose xyz.com which is in your mind , just type T followed by that it will open it in new tab . OR do you mean you want to open a url on the screen instead of pressing right mouse button and clicking on OPEN IN NEW TAB

Comment: When I press T, and then start typing gmail.com, the gmail.com gets appended to the end of the current URL. Does your Pentadactyl do something different?

Comment: yes please it actually opens the new tab with the url i typed . please download the nightlies here . http://5digits.org/nightlies

Comment: I would downvote if I had more rep. Typing T does NOT let you type in a new URL, it autofills the current page's URL.

Answer (score 0):

`C-t` is special in Pentadactyl:

> Execute the next [count] mappings in a new tab.

(see dactyl://help/tabs#%3CC-t%3E - `:h <C-t>`).

You could overwrite this mapping:

```
nmap <c-t> <Pass>
```

Or use another one:

```
nmap <C-t><C-t> :tabnew<cr>
```